# How come spark job is completed before all the tasks gets completed?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

I noticed the spark job which ran got completed even if all the tasks are not completed associated with it. Is it a common scenario? Is there any logic behind it?

[image]

Comment: share the complete image plz.

Comment: Possibly a bug imho.

Comment: It would be a good idea to share the spark version and maybe also an example which causes this

Comment: @AssafMendelson spark version : 2.01 and regarding usecase, I am doing a group by based on partition date for duration 30 days. Data is 10gb per partition distributed.